# How to show that $\mathbb E_{X,X'} \left[\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^mk(x_i,x_j) \right] = 2m\mathbb E_{x\sim p} [k(x,x)]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, notation

I posted a related question also to [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4332514/sum-of-sample-expectations-of-function-of-2-variables-understanding-mmd).

Basically, I would like to know how to show the following, which is part of [this paper](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume13/gretton12a/gretton12a.pdf):

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{m} \mathbb E_{X,X'}\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^m\left(k(x_i, x_j) + k(x_i', x_j') -k(x_i,x_j') - k(x_i',x_j)\right)\right]^\frac{1}{2} \\
\leq & \frac{1}{m}\left[2m\mathbb E_xk(x,x) + 2m(m-1)\mathbb E_{x,x'}k(x,x')-2m^2\mathbb E_{x,x'}k(x,x')\right]^\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

As part of this, I am asking:

How to proof that for samples $X,X'$ of size $m$ and with distribution $p$ we have that

\begin{align}
&\mathbb E_{X,X'} \left[\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^mk(x_i,x_j) \right]\\
= & 2m\mathbb E_{x\sim p} [k(x,x)]
\end{align}

where $x_i \in X, x_i'\in X'$ for all $i=1,\dots,m$, and $\mathbb E_{X,X'}$ denotes the expectation over all possible i.i.d. samples $X,X'$.

$k(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a (real-valued) kernel function, i.e., it is symmetric in its arguments and zero if both arguments are the same.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the question is ill-posed. In fact, to follow the proof, it suffices to reorder the terms in the sum as to arrive at the proper solution (handling the diagonal-elements separately).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).